# SWING JTable: How do I make each row as high as it's tallest object?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table , where some objects are rendered and are of non-fixed size (list of attributes). I want each row to be as high as it's tallest object , and I was wondering of to do it. I thought about doing something like this (see below) , but I'm sure there's something better..

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                 boolean isSelected,
                                                 boolean hasFocus, int row,
                                                 int column)
  {
      /*....*/

      this.setListData((Object[])value);
      int height = new Double(getPreferredSize().getHeight()).intValue();
      if (table.getRowHeight(row) < height)
          table.setRowHeight(row, height);    
      /*....*/

      return this;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have code like that in a renderer. Instead, when you load the data into the model, do something like:

```
private void updateRowHeights()
{
    try
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++)
        {
            int rowHeight = table.getRowHeight();

            for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++)
            {
                Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(table.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
                rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, comp.getPreferredSize().height);
            }

            table.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
        }
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e) {}
}
```

Comment: thanks - but can you elaborate a little on why I shouldn't have this kind of code inside a renderer? I have a gut feeling that it's wrong , but I don't know why..

Comment: A renderer is used to display a value in a cell of a table. It should not be used to change properties of the table. It should not need to know anything about the table, only the data to display.

Comment: Sounds right , thanks.  However , when is this function running? when should I call it?

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with the solution you have. I don't think there is a simpler way to do this.  No matter what you are going to have the check the height of each cell, so you might as well do that as you render each one.